# Properly overloading [bracket] operator for hashtable get and set

Tags: c++, exception, operator-overloading, hashtable, getter-setter

I am trying to implement a hashtable class. The problem I am facing atm is how to properly overload the square bracket operators so that getting the value at a key from the hashtable is distinguishable from setting a key to a value.

So far here is what the class looks like:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class HashTable {
    typedef pair<K, V> KeyVal;
    avl_tree <KeyVal> **TABLE;
    unsigned TABLESIZE;
    
public:
    HashTable( const unsigned & );
    V& operator [] ( const K& ); //Setter
    const V& operator [](const K&) const; //Getter
    typedef unsigned (*hashtype)(const K&);
    static hashtype Hash;
    ~HashTable();
};
```

And this is the implementation of each overload of the brackets:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
V& HashTable<K, V>::operator [] ( const K& ret ) {
    unsigned index = HashTable<K, V>::Hash(ret) % TABLESIZE;
    avl_tree <KeyVal> *ptr = AVL_TREE::find(TABLE[index], KeyVal(ret, 0));
    if ( ptr == None ) ptr = (TABLE[index] = AVL_TREE::insert(TABLE[index], KeyVal(ret, 0)));
    return ptr->data.second;
}

template <typename K, typename V>
const V& HashTable<K, V>::operator [](const K& ret) const {
    avl_tree <KeyVal> *ptr = AVL_TREE::find(TABLE[HashTable<K, V>::Hash(ret) % TABLESIZE], KeyVal(ret, 0));
    if (ptr == None) throw "Exception: [KeyError] Key not found exception.";
    return ptr->data.second;
}
```

Now if I do:

```
cout << table["hash"] << "\n"; //table declared as type HashTable<std::string, int>
```

I get an output of 0, but I want it to use the getter implementation of the overloaded square brackets; i.e. this should throw an exception. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to access `table` via a `const` reference or pointer, otherwise the non-const overload will be chosen.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by `access table via const reference or pointer`?

Comment: For example, `void foo(const HashTable<K,V>& t) { std::cout << t["hash"] << "\n";`.

Comment: So you are saying I need a reference to the table in order for the getter method to be called? But what if I am in main and I do something like what I've shown above? How would I overload those operators to do what I need? Or should I just overload the `=` operator?

Comment: Your overloads are generally OK, there is no clean way around this. In the standard library, the approach is to provide only a non-const `operator []`, and provide `const` and non-`const` member functions `at()`, both of which doing range checking and throwing if the key is not found. I have added an example expanding on my first comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to handle this situation is to have `operator[]` return a proxy.

Then, for the proxy overload `operator T` approximately as you've done your `const` overload above. Overload `operator=` about like your non-const version.

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class HashTable {
    typedef pair<K, V> KeyVal;
    avl_tree <KeyVal> **TABLE;
    unsigned TABLESIZE;

    template <class K, class V>
    class proxy { 
        HashTable<K, V> &h;
        K key;
    public:
        proxy(HashTable<K, V> &h, K key) : h(h), key(key) {}

        operator V() const { 
            auto pos = h.find(key);
            if (pos) return *pos;
            else throw not_present();
        }

        proxy &operator=(V const &value) {
            h.set(key, value);
            return *this;
        }
    };
public:
    HashTable( const unsigned & );

    proxy operator [] ( const K& k) { return proxy(*this, k); }
    typedef unsigned (*hashtype)(const K&);
    static hashtype Hash;
    ~HashTable();
};
```

You basically have two cases when you use this:

```
some_hash_table[some_key] = some_value;

value_type v = some_hash_table[some_key];
```

In both cases, `some_hash_table[some_key]` returns an instance of `proxy`. In the first case, you're assigning *to* the proxy object, so that invokes the proxy's `operator=`, passing it `some_value`, so `some_value` gets added to the table with `key` as its key.

In the second case, you're trying to assign an object of type `proxy` to a variable of type `value_type`. Obviously that can't be assigned directly -- but `proxy::operator V` returns an object of the value type for the underlying `Hashtable` -- so the compiler invokes that to produce a value that can be assigned to `v`. That, in turn, checks for the presence of the proper key in the table, and throws an exception if its not present.

Comment: I think you forgot one more parameter in the constructor of the proxy: `proxy(HashTable<K, V> const &h, const K& Key) : h(h), key(Key) {}` ?

Comment: @Smac89: Oops -- yes, looks like I had. And actually, in this case the parameter needs to be a non-const reference too.

Comment: What is the return type of `operator V() const`?

Comment: @Smac89: `V`. In general, for some conversion operator `operator T`, the return type is implicitly `T`.

Comment: Thank you for this Jerry. I am close to completion but my brain is tired so I will continue tomorrow

Comment: I am surprised that this worked as well as it did. But my question is, if the `proxy operator []` returns a proxy object; how is it still read as `int`? Supposing I did the assignment `table["hashthis"] = 99` then I do `cout << table["hashthis"]`. How is this returning int and printing the value 99?

Comment: Magic! Seriously, each use of `table["hashthis"]` returns a proxy object that overloads both `operator=(V)` and `operator V`. The first allows assignment of a V (in this case, `V` = `int`), and the second allows conversion of the proxy to a V. So, when you assign to the proxy, it calls `proxy::operator=(V)`, and when you use its value, it calls `proxy::operator V`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36992/discussion-between-smac89-and-jerry-coffin)

Answer (score 2):

When equivalent `const` and non-`const` overloads of a member function or operator are available, the non-const is chosen when the method is called on a non-`const` instance. The `const` overload will only be picked if the instance is `const`, or if it is accessed via a `const` reference or pointer:

```
struct Foo
{
  void foo() {}
  void foo() const {}
};

void bar(const Foo& f) { f.foo();}
void baz(const Foo* f) { f->foo(); }

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  f.foo(); // non-const overload chosen
  bar(f);  // const overload chosen
  bar(&f); // const overload chosen

  const Foo cf; // const instance
  cf.foo();     // const overload chosen

  const Foo& rf = f; // const reference
  rf.foo();          // const overload chosen
}
```